# Redis / Node.js - 2 clients (1 pub/sub) causing issues with writes

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, publish-subscribe

Trying to create two clients; one is pub/sub, the other is a standard connection.  Is this not possible?  There must be a way to abstract this to  work :)  Basically, if I do a `get key` after running test.js, all I see is 'valueBefore'.  The output:

```
node test.js 
Reply: OK

/Users/franklovecchio/Desktop/development/node/node_modules/redis/index.js:487
        throw new Error("Connection in pub/sub mode, only pub/sub commands may
              ^
Error: Connection in pub/sub mode, only pub/sub commands may be used
    at RedisClient.send_command (/Users/franklovecchio/Desktop/development/node/node_modules/redis/index.js:487:15)
    at RedisClient.<anonymous> (/Users/franklovecchio/Desktop/development/node/node_modules/redis/index.js:597:27)
    at Object._onTimeout (/Users/franklovecchio/Desktop/development/node/distributed-cache/client/test.js:19:12)
    at Timer.callback (timers.js:83:39)
```

The code:

```
var redis = require('redis');

var client1 = redis.createClient();
var client2 = redis.createClient();

client2.on('message', function (channel, message) {
    console.log('Received a message on channel: ' + channel);       

    client1.set('key', message, redis.print);

});

client2.subscribe('channel');

client1.set('key', 'valueBefore', redis.print);

setTimeout(
    function() {
        client2.publish('channel', 'valueAfter');
    },3000
);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably need to publish messages from `client1` since `client2` is dedicated to listening for messages on certain channel. Few words about this behavior are written in [node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) readme:

> If you need to send regular commands to Redis while in pub/sub mode,
>   just open another connection.